# What is acc in my question votes?

Tags: support, recent-activity

I saw "acc" in my question votes where were supposed to be the number of votes. What does it mean?

Comment: This question is suspiciously devoid of screenshots with freehand circles.

Comment: @Ether what? (I don't speak english very well, is "freehands circles" an expression?)

Comment: @Ether if you mean screenshots with circles showing the problem, it was not needed. The answer was already correctly given.. I don't understand the purpose of this comment..

Comment: @Ether by the way, @ChrisF's answer in my comment is right, it was not hiden the number of votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the answer was accepted.

Comment: Since he's talking about his "question votes", it means he accepted an answer.

Comment: it should not hide the number of votes.. anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Tom - it doesn't. It's a separate entry to the votes. If you go to your recent activity page the summary only shows the top 5 recent scores, so if you got one upvote and an acceptance (along with 4 other votes) the upvote may well disappear of the bottom as it's only worth 10 while the acceptance is worth 15. Go to the "reputation" tab and click "today" to see the full list.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're viewing the alt text for an image that didn't load.  Did you look at the HTML source?